# -[NSWindowController window] retaining window when NSWindowController initialized with window?

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

In an application (OS X 10.6.7) I have a `NSWindowController` subclass which is initialized with `-[NSWindowController initWithWindow:]`—i.e., I have already created the window in code; I'm not loading it from a nib.

Normally, I refer to the window in my `NSWindowController` subclasses with `[self window]`. But in this case, every time I send `[self window]`, the window gets retained, so I end up leaking quite a lot.

Is this intended behavior?  For the moment I've worked around it by just storing the window in an instance variable in the `init` method and never sending `[self window]`.

I am pretty sure this is not happening because `NSWindowController` is trying to load the window: `-loadWindow` does not retain the window and `-isWindowLoaded` returns `YES`:

```
(gdb) set $window = (id)[self window]
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) p (int)[$window retainCount]
$1 = 3
(gdb) p (BOOL)[self isWindowLoaded]
$2 = 1 '\001'
(gdb) call (void)[self loadWindow]
(gdb) p (int)[$window retainCount]
$3 = 3
(gdb) p (int)[[self window] retainCount]
$4 = 4
(gdb) p (int)[[self window] retainCount]
$5 = 5
```

Comment: It could be the case that `-window` does something like `return [[_window retain] autorelease]`, and your debugging session doesn’t give a chance for the corresponding autorelease pool to be drained. Is there an _actual_ leak?

Comment: Yes, there's an actual leak. Note the "before close" above; this happens when I'm trying to close the window, and the retain count is directly proportional to the number of `[self window]` invocations.  I just found another mention of this, too: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/219582-nswindowcontroller-retain-counts-chapter-2.html

Comment: I see that thread has covered the `-retain/-autorelease` pattern, and that unbalanced autorelease pool comment is interesting. Other than that, I’m out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks, after coming back to it, you were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-[NSWindowController window]` retaining the window is fine; the issue seems to be related to autorelease pools.

```
window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 200, 200)
                                               styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask
                                                 backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                   defer:NO];
NSWindowController *controller = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindow:window];
[window setTitle:@"testing"];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[window release];
NSLog(@"[window retainCount]: %d", [window retainCount]);
[controller window];
[controller window];
[controller window];
NSLog(@"[window retainCount]: %d", [window retainCount]);

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
[controller window];
[controller window];
[controller window];
NSLog(@"[window retainCount]: %d", [window retainCount]);
[pool drain];
NSLog(@"[window retainCount]: %d", [window retainCount]);
```

The output is:

```
2011-06-12 19:26:52.337 window[5517:a0b] [window retainCount]: 1
2011-06-12 19:26:52.339 window[5517:a0b] [window retainCount]: 4
2011-06-12 19:26:52.340 window[5517:a0b] [window retainCount]: 7
2011-06-12 19:26:52.340 window[5517:a0b] [window retainCount]: 4
```

The problem was that I forgot to create a pool when doing Cocoa stuff in a Carbon event handler (`InstallApplicationEventHandler`).  This matches the context of the thread I linked to.

Ordinarily I see an exception when there's no autorelease pool present, so I'm guessing there is simply a pool in place that never gets drained.